# How can I autorun my app based on a file's existence instead of autorun.inf on SD Card?

Tags: windows, autorun, autoplay

I have a device that creates a file called ADxxxxxx.BIN on an SD Card (where "xxxxxx" is a unique number). I'd like to be able to insert this SD Card into a USB card reader (connected to a Windows XP/Vista/7 system) and have my custom application launch automatically and perform some processing on that .BIN file. I do not want to have to create an autorun.inf file on the SD Card.

Is it possible to configure the system to auto run my application based on the presence of the .BIN filename without having to add an autorun.inf file to the SD card?

Comment: I certainly hope not. Autorun.inf is a big enough security risk for users that don't know better than to leave it enabled; being able to do something based on a `something.bin` file launching an app would be even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not possible. What you can do is have some software running on the machine and checking for new devices that has your `ADxxxxxx.BIN` file

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That probably won't be a good option for my app, but I'll keep that in mind.